# Determine the locus of a equation Quickly[Mental Math]

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, conic-sections, locus

if $Z=X+iy$ then determine the locus of the equation $\left | 2Z-1 \right | = \left | Z-2 \right |$.I can tell that it a circle equation and it is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.There are a lot of equation in my book such as $\left | Z-8 \right | +\left | Z+8 \right |=20$,$\left | Z-2 \right | = \left | Z-3i  \right |$,$\left | 2Z+3 \right |= \left | Z+6 \right |$.Every time I have to do a long calculation.
Is there any short way to find out that if the given equation is circle,ellipse, parabola, hyperbola or straight line.This is needed for my MCQ exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|2z-1| = |z-2|$:

Rearrange to $|z-\frac12| = \frac12|z-2|$: distance from $\frac12$ is half distance from $2$.

So it's a circle (distance from one point is a constant multiple $-$ not $0$ or $1$ $-$ of distance from another point). You know two points on the diameter: $1$ and $-1$. So you know the centre and radius.

$|z-8|+|z+8|=20$:

Distance from one point + distance from another point is constant: an ellipse with the two points as foci.

$|z-2| = |z-3i|$:

Distance from one point = distance from another point: this is the perpendicular bisector of the two points.

$|2z+3| = |z+6|$:

Rearrange to $|z+\frac32| = \frac12|z+6|$ and it's the same case as the first equation.

Answer (score 2):

Some fundamental equations:

$|z - z_0| = \rho$: circle with center $K(z_0)$ and radius  $\rho$.

$|z - z_1| = |z - z_2|$: perpendicular bisector of the line segment with end points $K(z_1)$ and $K(z_2)$.

$|z-z_1| + |z-z_2| = 2a, \, a>0 \text{ and } |z_1-z_2|<2a $: ellipse with foci $E(z_1),E'(z_2)$ and constant sum $2a$ (recall the definition of the ellipse.)

$|z - a| = |Re(z) + a|,\, a\in \mathbb R \iff y^2 = 4ax: \text { parabola.}$

$|z - a\cdot i| =|Im(z) + a|,\, a\in \mathbb R \iff x^2 = 4ay: \text{ parabola.}$

$\big||z-z_1| - |z-z_2|\big|=2a,\, a>0 \text{ and } 2a<|z_1 - z_2|$: hyperbola with foci $E(z_1),E'(z_2)$ and constant absolute difference $2a$ (recall the definition of the hyperbola).

---

*Note*: In general, $|z-z_0|$ expresses the distance between the images $M(z)$ and $M(z_0)$.